# Is there an English translation of Moritz Cantor’s History of Mathematics?

Tags: mathematics

I have heard about the high regard in which Moritz Cantor’s multi-volume work on the History of Mathematics has been held among mathematicians and historians alike. I am becoming increasingly interested in the History, and missing out on such a work would, in my view, be a cardinal sin. I, however, have not been able to find any sort of translation of the Work into English (the original language is German), which I find very odd, given the good repute of the Treatise. I have not even seen any amateur translations. It would be very nice if some here could provide me with at least a hint where I might look for a translation, or say why one has not been made yet (if it truly has not been made yet). I am genuinely curious!

Comment: I could not find any translations. Hathi trust has four volumes and Internet Archive has three volumes. I do not know enough German, but if you would like to read certain segments, you can try using DeepL translator. More details are described in "Facile Solutions to the Problems Associated with Chemical Information and Mathematical Symbolism While Using Machine Translation Tools" https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00274

Comment: [MAA presented it](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-moritz-cantors-history-of-mathematics) as a "mathematical treasure" and mentioned no translations, so probably none exist.